# Swift string interception the previous paragraph of a character

Tags: swift

How to intercept the string before `-` and `:`

```
let str = "fist:hello-world";
```

I want to `fist` string

If I'm in Javascript, I'm going to find the first character I encounter get its subscript and intercept it, but what do I do in swift?

I tried some apis, but no, can you help me?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you want to do and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Show what you've tried so far and give example input and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get anything before either ':' or '-' you can use `prefix` in combination with `firstIndex`

```
let firstPart = input.prefix(upTo:input.firstIndex { $0 == ":" || $0 == "-"} ?? input.endIndex)
```

Example

```
let examples = ["hello:more stuff", "hello, more-stuff", "hello, more stuff"]

for input in examples {
    print(input.prefix(upTo:input.firstIndex { $0 == ":" || $0 == "-"} ?? input.endIndex))
}
```

Output

> hello
>   hello, more
>   hello, more stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = "hello:worl-d"
let components = str.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: ":-"))
let result = components[0] // result = "hello"
```

Comment: If both: and - what to do?

Comment: Give me an example mate?

Comment: "hello:wro-d" Intercept if one of them is encountered, e.g: I want to "hello"

Comment: Glad that I helped, don't forget to mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

@soufian-hossiam is *very* close, but if you want to use multiple "split characters" like you suggest in your comment to his answer you can use a custom [`CharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset)

And then split the String into an array like so:

```
let splitCharacters = CharacterSet([":", "-"])
let testString = "Hello:wor-ld"
let components = testString.components(separatedBy: splitCharacters)
```

Now the `testString` is split into pieces in the `components` array and you can then use that array to get to the individual pieces.

For instance

```
for component in components {
    print(component)
}
```

returns:

> Hello
>
> wor
>
> ld

Hope that helps.